# Should I reuse the same LINQ IQueryable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

If I have the following LINQ Query:

```
public class _employeeRepository 
{
    public IQueryable<Employee> getAll()
    {
         var q = from e in Employees select e;
         return q;
    }
}
```

..should I do below to get the active employees

```
public IQueryable<Employee> getActiveEmployees>()
{
    return _employeeRepository.getAll().Where(q => q.active);
}
```

..or should I create a separate function?

```
public class _employeeRepository 
{
    public IQueryable<Employee> getAll()
    {
         var q = from e in Employees select e;
         return q;
    }

    public IQueryable<Employee> getActive()
    {
        var q = from e in Employees where e.active == true select e;
    }
}
```

What is the advantage or disadvantage of doing it one way or the other?

Comment: Your `getAll` method is pretty pointless as it stands.  It's just `return Employees;`.  That's either just making `Employees` accessible publicly if it's not currently, or just creating a new member that's identical to another.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To expand on @Servy's comment: If you are coming from a Java background (because of the lower case methods), you might feel wrong directly exposing a propertly like `Employees`, but it's ok in the .net world, because the access to it is still controlled via (implicit) setter and getter methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `GetActive` and `GetActiveEmployees` will do the exact same thing, i.e. generate a query and hold it for execution.

The query will **not** be send to a database until you "materialize" it, i.e. with a call to `ToList` or by using the `IQueryable` in a `foreach` statement.

Then, and only then will the query (in both cases similar to `select * from Employees where IsActive=1`) execute

That said, it's better to reuse code when you can, so I'll go with the first approach.